# When using NSFileWrapper, is there a way to handle huge output files by writing multiple times with chunks of NSData objects?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilewrapper

I a macOS Cocoa application, I need to save a Bundle in my app proprietary format. For this reason, I decided to look at NSFileWrapper that appears to be the cleanest solution to deal with the problem. My code looks like this:

```
NSFileWrapper *bundleFileWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initDirectoryWithFileWrappers:nil];

NSDictionary *fileWrappers = [bundleFileWrapper fileWrappers];

if ([fileWrappers objectForKey:mboxFileName] == nil) {
    NSFileWrapper *textFileWrapper = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:mboxData];
    [textFileWrapper setPreferredFilename:mboxFileName];
    [bundleFileWrapper addFileWrapper:textFileWrapper];
}
NSError *error;

BOOL success = [bundleFileWrapper writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] options:NSFileWrapperWritingAtomic originalContentsURL:NULL error:&error];

NSLog(@"Error = %@",[error localizedDescription]);
```

My problem is that to I end up using very large NSData objects and this approach takes a lot of memory. Is there a way using NSFileWrapper to write small NSData objects in sequence ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, if the data for a regular file wrapper is too big to fit in memory, then `NSFileWrapper` probably isn't the best choice. Consider just writing the file/package directly, or (maybe?) use wrappers for the structure of the package, but then write the embedded files directly. If that's not feasible, please explain why you need to use `NSFileWrapper`.

Comment: Thanks, your comment answers my question. I think I will use NSFileWrapper for the structure as you suggest, then use fwrite for the big data. I use NSFileWrapper because I like that it provides an object oriented clean way to handle the creation of bundles. If you want, answer the question with your comment, I will accept certainly the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider not using `NSFileWrapper` for your large data files. Use `NSFileWrapper` for the directory structure, but write big data files directly (`open`, `write`, ...).

Also, don't be shy about simply creating the directory structure yourself. A package can be as simple as, literally, a folder with an extension. And there are still tons of O-O APIs (`NSURL`, `NSFileManager`, ...) to help you examine and manipulate its content.

Good luck!